# "trap ... INT TERM EXIT" really necessary?

Tags: bash, shell, signals, trap

Many examples for `trap` use `trap ... INT TERM EXIT` for cleanup tasks. But is it really necessary to list all the three sigspecs?

[The manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html):

> If a SIGNAL_SPEC is EXIT (0) ARG is executed on exit from the shell.

which I believe applies whether the script finished normally or it finished because it received `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`. An experiment also confirms my belief:

```
$ cat ./trap-exit
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo TRAP' EXIT
sleep 3
$ ./trap-exit & sleep 1; kill -INT %1
[1] 759
TRAP
[1]+  Interrupt               ./trap-exit
$ ./trap-exit & sleep 1; kill -TERM %1
[1] 773
TRAP
[1]+  Terminated              ./trap-exit
```

Then why do so many examples list all of `INT TERM EXIT`? Or did I miss something and is there any case where a sole `EXIT` would miss?

Comment: Also keep in mind that with a spec like `INT TERM EXIT` the cleanup code is executed twice when `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` is received.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/trap.html) doesn't say much about the conditions resulting in executing the EXIT trap, only about what its environment must look like when it is executed.

In Busybox's ash shell, your trap-exit test does not echo 'TRAP' before exiting due to either SIGINT or SIGTERM. I would suspect there are other shells in existance that may not work that way as well.

```
# /tmp/test.sh & sleep 1; kill -INT %1
# 
[1]+  Interrupt                  /tmp/test.sh
# 
# 
# /tmp/test.sh & sleep 1; kill -TERM %1
# 
[1]+  Terminated                 /tmp/test.sh
#
```

Comment: `dash` also doesn't trap on just `EXIT` when it receives `SIGINT/SIGTERM`.

Comment: `zsh` as well - thus, perhaps `bash` is the only shell where `EXIT` also does match signals.

Comment: @maxschlepzig `zsh` doesn't trap on `EXIT` when it receives `INT`,  but it does when it receives `TERM`. EDIT: I just noticed how old this was...

Answer (score 42):

**Yes, there is a difference.**

This script will exit when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or send it `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`:

```
trap '' EXIT
echo ' --- press ENTER to close --- '
read response
```

This script will exit when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
trap '' EXIT INT TERM
echo ' --- press ENTER to close --- '
read response
```

* Tested in *sh*, *Bash*, and *Zsh*.   (no longer works in *sh* when you add a command for trap to run)

---

There's also what @Shawn said: *Ash* and *Dash* don't trap signals with `EXIT`.

So, to handle signals robustly, it's best to avoid trapping `EXIT` altogether, and use something like this:

```
cleanup() {
    echo "Cleaning stuff up..."
    exit
}

trap cleanup INT TERM
echo ' --- press ENTER to close --- '
read var
cleanup
```

Comment: The solution with cleanup does the right thing - very elegant! It has become an idiom for my bash scripts with `mktemp` calls.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have shellscript errors in your code that cause it to exit prematurely.

Comment: @ijw: In Bash and Ksh, you can trap `ERR` to handle that, but [it is not portable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Debugging_and_signal_handling#Err..._ERR.3F).

Comment: This solution isn't robust when another shell calls it. It doesn't handle [wait on cooperative exit](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html); you will want to `trap - INT TERM; kill -2 $$` as the last line of cleanup, to tell the parent shell that it exited prematurely. If a parent shell foobar.sh calls your script (foo.sh), and then calls bar.sh, you don't want bar.sh to execute if INT/TERM is sent to your foo.sh.

`trap cleanup EXIT` will handle this propagation automatically, so it is IMO the most robust. It also means you wouldn't have to call `cleanup` at the end of the script.

Comment: Doing `kill -2 $$` will propagate up the chain of non-interactive shells, killing each parent shell, and then stop at the first interactive shell, giving stdin back to the keyboard (Which is as excepted, ctrl+c should return to the interactive shell, not hang). Quite sad ash doesn't work with `EXIT` as bash makes it real easy (so nvm on EXIT being robust if you're talking compatibility), but the kill is important there.

Comment: @Zaz: Could you incorporate the comments and the [two-trap variation from the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322213/26216) into your answer. As it currently stands, your answer makes a great point but isn't really as robust as it claims.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone Mere `trap cleanup EXIT` will not do, if you want to interupt the "ping" loop at  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#Special_Note_On_SIGINT_and_SIGQUIT

Answer (score 15):

Refining the last answer, because it has issues:

```
# Our general exit handler
cleanup() {
    err=$?
    echo "Cleaning stuff up..."
    trap '' EXIT INT TERM
    exit $err 
}
sig_cleanup() {
    trap '' EXIT # some shells will call EXIT after the INT handler
    false # sets $?
    cleanup
}
trap cleanup EXIT
trap sig_cleanup INT QUIT TERM
```

Points above:

INT and TERM handlers don't quit for me when I test - they handle the error then the shell returns to exiting (and this is not too surprising).  So I ensure that the cleanup exits afterwards, and in the case of the signals always uses an error code (and in the other case of a normal exit, preserves the error code).

With bash, it seems that exiting in the INT handler also calls the EXIT handler, hence I untrap the exit handler and call it myself (which will work in any shell regardless of behaviour).

I trap exit because shell scripts can exit before they reach the bottom - syntax errors, set -e and a nonzero return, simply calling exit.  You can't rely on a shellscript getting to the bottom.

SIGQUIT is Ctrl-\ if you've never tried it.  Gets you a bonus coredump.  So I think it's also worth trapping, even if it's a little obscure.

Past experience says if you (like me) always press Ctrl-C several times, you'll sometimes catch it half way through the cleanup part of your shell script, so this works but not always as perfectly as you'd like.

Comment: The caller would just get 1 as the exit code, no matter what signal caused the exit, while withour `trap` the caller would get 130 for SIGINT, 143 for SIGTERM, etc. So I would capture and pass the correct exit code as: `sig_cleanup() { err=$?; trap '' EXIT; (exit $err); cleanup; }`.

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of `trap '' EXIT INT TERM` in the cleanup function? Is this to prevent accidental user interruption of cleanup that you mentioned in the last paragraph? Isn't the `EXIT` redundant?

Comment: With `set -o errexit`, calling `false` in `sig_cleanup()` impedes `cleanup()` from being called. In this case, `trap cleanup EXIT` seems sufficient.

Comment: @musiphil - `err=$?` in `sig_cleanup` only gives 0 in dash, so apparently the original signal code is lost when trapping signals there, and that's why something like calling `false` is required. But as @Enno says, this would need a `set +e` in `sig_cleanup` to avoid exiting before `cleanup` is called.

Comment: @mstorsjo `err=$?` seems to work in dash 0.5.10.2-6; by which version did you try?

Comment: @musiphil why not use `sig_cleanup() { err=$?; trap - EXIT; cleanup; exit $err; }`?

Comment: @jarno - I tried dash 0.5.8-2.10 (ubuntu 18.04), and I can confirm that I see that it behaves the way you describe in dash 0.5.10.2. I bisected it down to this change, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/commit/?id=d28c13e7119a605ef152a4310e9415dc7ae9b8f3, which was included in dash 0.5.9.

Comment: @mstorsjo if the changed code is already in 0.5.8, how could the change be in 0.5.9? BTW In my experience mere `exit` works in dash, too, but it does not work in bash.

Comment: @jarno - No, the change is in 0.5.9. With 0.5.8, `$?` is zero in `sig_cleanup()`, in 0.5.9 and onwards it has the actual signal return value.

Comment: @mstorsjo I tested it in Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked. `$?` is 130 after Ctrl-C. It has dash 0.5.8-2.10.

Comment: @jarno With https://pastebin.com/d74jkFVU on Ubuntu 18.04 I'm getting `$?` in `sig_cleanup`, if I press ctrl+c during the sleep. With a newer dash I'm getting 130 there.

Comment: @mstorsjo oh, but that is only, if you have errexit flag set. I do not see why it should affect, though. And in never version it is fixed.

Comment: @mstorsjo see also my related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60780615/4414935).

Answer (score 8):

This is how you can make the Bash script report its return code `$?`, while being able to catch the SIGINT and SIGTERM signals. I find this very useful for scripts running in a CI/CD pipeline:

```
notify() {
    [[ $1 = 0 ]] || echo ❌ EXIT $1
    # you can notify some external services here,
    # ie. Slack webhook, Github commit/PR etc.
}

trap '(exit 130)' INT
trap '(exit 143)' TERM
trap 'rc=$?; notify $rc; exit $rc' EXIT
```

Comment: Redirecting INT and TERM to the EXIT trap is an elegant solution, which prevents dual calls to the trap command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve, and which shells you're targeting. For `bash` it's probably okay to just use `EXIT`. But [not all shells](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/c599da097ae610066ff5e3106150ed37) invoke the `EXIT` handler on `SIGINT`/`SIGTERM`.

For them you can try to set one handler for several signals (`trap '...' INT EXIT`), but then it may be invoked several times:

```
$ bash -c 'trap "echo trap" INT EXIT; sleep 3' & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $pid; wait
[1] 276923
trap
trap
[1]+  Done                    bash -c 'trap "echo trap" INT EXIT; sleep 3'
```

So either you write it with that in mind, or you can try to [forward](https://newbedev.com/exit-trap-in-dash-vs-ksh-and-bash) everything to the `EXIT` handler:

```
$ bash -c 'trap "exit 123" INT; trap "echo EXIT \$?" EXIT; sleep 3' & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $pid; wait
[1] 286229
EXIT 123
[1]+  Exit 123                bash -c 'trap "exit 123" INT; trap "echo EXIT \$?" EXIT; sleep 3'
```

But if you set up a handler for `SIGINT`, you generally want it to [kill the script with `SIGINT`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#Special_Note_On_SIGINT_and_SIGQUIT):

`a.sh`:

```
trap 'exit 123' INT
trap 'echo EXIT $?; trap - INT; kill -INT $$' EXIT
sleep 3
```

```
$ bash h.sh & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $pid; wait $pid
[1] 236263
EXIT 123
[1]+  Interrupt               bash h.sh
```

And under Debian < 10 (`dash < 0.5.10`) the [signal that killed the script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/when-does-the-system-send-a-sigterm-to-a-process) (if any) [is not passed](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/addecad8b7668ac20add6c648598ef2e).

The solution I came up with:

```
set -eu
cleanup() {
    echo "cleanup ($1)"
    trap - INT TERM EXIT  # avoid reexecuting handlers
    if [ "$1" = 130 ]; then
        kill -INT $$
    elif [ "$1" = 143 ]; then
        kill -TERM $$
    else
        exit "$1"
    fi
}
trap 'cleanup 130' INT
trap 'cleanup 143' TERM
trap 'cleanup $?' EXIT

if [ "${1-}" = fail ]; then
    no-such-command
fi
sleep 3
```

```
$ bash f.sh; echo $?
cleanup (0)
0

$ bash f.sh fail; echo $?
f.sh: line 20: no-such-command: command not found
cleanup (127)
127

$ bash f.sh & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $pid; wait $pid
[1] 282422
cleanup (130)
[1]+  Interrupt               bash f.sh

$ bash f.sh & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -TERM $pid; wait $pid
[1] 282458
cleanup (143)
[1]+  Terminated              bash f.sh
```

Tested in:

- `bash`: `5.1.8`
- dash: `0.5.10`, `0.5.8`, `0.5.7`
- Alpine Linux 3.14 (`busybox`)

Answer (score 0):

I found no 100% perfect answer, but @ijw answer and @musiphil comment were very close:
["trap ... INT TERM EXIT" really necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57940/trap-int-term-exit-really-necessary#comment568155_322213)

The problem with their answers:

- if you press many times Ctrl^C, the cleanup function is repeated which is not what we would usually expect

Here's a proper code I tested under bash and POSIX sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Script to test traps

# If interrupted:
# - SIGINT: Ctrl^C (kill -2), exit code 128+2=130
# - SIGTERM: kill -15, allows a graceful termination 
#            unlike kill -9 that cannot be trapped
#            exit code 128+15=143
# - SIGQUIT: Ctrl^\ or kill -3, like SIGINT but do a core dump
#            exit code 128+3=131
# - EXIT:    on any exit reason. On some shells, it is always called
#            even after SIGINT, SIGTERM...
#            this causes the clean function to be called twice,
#            unless we cancel the trap like in sig_cleanup()
#            we need to save the exit code when calling cleanup function
# If left to properly finish, simulate error exit 2 to test script exit code (Signal EXIT)

# Our test function to handle cleanup:
some_job() {
    echo "Working hard on some stuff..."
    for i in $(seq 1 5); do
        #printf "."
        printf '%s' "$i."
        sleep 1
    done

    echo ""
    echo "Job done, but we found some errors !"
    return 2 # to simulate script exit code 2
}

# Our clean temp files function
# - should not be interrupted
# - should not be called twice if interrupted
clean_tempfiles() {
    echo ""
    echo "Cleaning temp files, do not interrupt..."
    for i in $(seq 1 5); do
        printf "> "
        sleep 1
    done
    echo ""
}

# Called on signal EXIT, or indirectly on INT QUIT TERM
clean_exit() {
    # save the return code of the script
    err=$?

    # reset trap for all signals to not interrupt clean_tempfiles() on any next signal
    trap '' EXIT INT QUIT TERM

    clean_tempfiles
    exit $err # exit the script with saved $?
}

# Called on signals INT QUIT TERM
sig_cleanup() {
    # save error code (130 for SIGINT, 143 for SIGTERM, 131 for SIGQUIT)
    err=$?

    # some shells will call EXIT after the INT signal
    # causing EXIT trap to be executed, so we trap EXIT after INT
    trap '' EXIT 

    (exit $err) # execute in a subshell just to pass $? to clean_exit()
    clean_exit
}

trap clean_exit EXIT
trap sig_cleanup INT QUIT TERM

some_job
exit # remove to test curl interruption
curl -T test.sh "tftp://10.0.10.55"
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will be executed on *HUP INT QUIT ABRT TERM and EXIT*. Assuring that it will not run twice like on INT and following EXIT.

```
#!/bin/sh
stty -echoctl # hide ^C when pressing ctrl + c
tmpFile=$(mktemp tmp-XXXXXX --suffix=.tmp -p "$TMPDIR")
declare -a signals=("HUP" "INT" "QUIT" "ABRT" "TERM" "EXIT") #array for all custom signal traps to cleanup

cleanup() { # function called by trap
    rc=$? #returnCode+128 of last command eg INT=2 +128 -> 130
    trap '' "${signals[@]}" # mute trap for all signals to not interrupt cleanup() on any next signal
    rm "${tmpFile}" #clearTmpFiles 
    exit "${rc}" #exit with returnCode+128 of last command
}
trap "cleanup" "${signals[@]}"
```

Tested with:

```
#!/bin/sh

exit 0
exit 1
exit 2
tr #EXIT TRAP RC 1
kill -INT $$ #interrupt signal #INT 2 RC 0
kill -QUIT $$ #interrupt signal #QUIT 3 RC 0
kill -ABRT $$ #ABRT signal #ABRT 6 RC 0
kill -KILL $$ #KILL yourself THIS IS NOT CAUGHT in cleanup #KILL 9 The SIGKILL signal cannot be trapped. It always immediately interrupts the script.
kill -TERM $$ #terminate yourself gently #TERM 15 RC 0

#AND THIS FOR GENERATING ERRORCODES
ping #EXIT TRAP RC 64
$((hg)) #EXIT TRAP RC 126 permission denied
/tmp/nosuchmethod #EXIT TRAP RC 127 no such file or dir
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, "why do so many examples list all of INT TERM EXIT?"