# losetup --detach not removing loopback device

Tags: loop-device

I am trying to detach a loopback device.

The `losetup --detach` presumably succeeds (no error message and return code 0) but the device is still there.

Any ideas?

```
root@Cassiopeia:~# losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [2053]:5243868 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6034.snap)
/dev/loop6: [2053]:19401380 (/tmp/imagefile)
/dev/loop4: [2053]:5249290 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_49.snap)
/dev/loop2: [2053]:5243293 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_50.snap)
/dev/loop0: [2053]:5249134 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_5897.snap)
/dev/loop5: [2053]:5249130 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6130.snap)
/dev/loop3: [2053]:5244442 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_54.snap)
root@Cassiopeia:~# losetup --detach /dev/loop6
root@Cassiopeia:~# echo $?
0
root@Cassiopeia:~# losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [2053]:5243868 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6034.snap)
/dev/loop6: [2053]:19401380 (/tmp/imagefile)
/dev/loop4: [2053]:5249290 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_49.snap)
/dev/loop2: [2053]:5243293 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_50.snap)
/dev/loop0: [2053]:5249134 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_5897.snap)
/dev/loop5: [2053]:5249130 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6130.snap)
/dev/loop3: [2053]:5244442 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_54.snap)
```

Comment: You have to umount them first.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old but I just came across a similar problem.

It's that way because something has the device still open, it doesn't have to be mounted. Try lsof and similar commands to find what is it.

It my case it was parted hanging on the other terminal ;)

Answer (score 2):

That happened to me too a while ago, and noticed this can happen in a number of ways:

- If you accessed one of the directories, through some terminal (eg, used `cd` and you didn't either closed said terminal or you're still on those said directories)
- If other process/command is using the mounted loop device/directories.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882272/12349101) answer, you can use:

```bsh
fuser -c /dev/loop0
fuser -d /dev/loop0
fuser -f /dev/loop0
```

To get all necessary information, such as PID, etc.

You can then use either `fuse -k` or `kill -9` if you *really must*, but do know it's probably a bad idea to force the termination of the process like this.

If you want to attempt to [gracefully](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366846/409852) `kill` it, (say, if you don't know how to access the process who use the mount/loop device):

```bsh
kill PID
```

should work.

Lastly, given that this is about `snap` (based on the output on your post) you [probably](https://askubuntu.com/a/983777/1093568) shouldn't try to remove or unmount them, unless you want to either uninstall snap completely or remove individual snap package.