# Which signal (like SIGINT or SIGTERM) can a process get when system is going to reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, c, signals, reboot

My application needs to do something before exit, I have already handled the ctrl-c case by handling signal of `SIGINT`, but I'd also like to handle the case when the system is going to reboot.

I researched a bit but found that `SIGTERM` is by administrative operation and system will not send `SIGTERM` before reboot, is it correct?

Any other signal that I can handle?

Edit:
If my application is run by `systemd`, does it make it more complicated or easier to handle?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499764/18455

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signals sent are customizable and that is documented in [`man systemd.kill`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html).  The most interesting parts are:

```
       KillSignal=
           Specifies which signal to use when stopping a service. This
           controls the signal that is sent as first step of shutting down a
           unit (see above), and is usually followed by SIGKILL (see above
           and below). For a list of valid signals, see signal(7). Defaults
           to SIGTERM.

           Note that, right after sending the signal specified in this
           setting, systemd will always send SIGCONT, to ensure that even
           suspended tasks can be terminated cleanly.

       FinalKillSignal=
           Specifies which signal to send to remaining processes after a
           timeout if SendSIGKILL= is enabled. The signal configured here
           should be one that is not typically caught and processed by
           services (SIGTERM is not suitable). Developers can find it useful
           to use this to generate a coredump to troubleshoot why a service
           did not terminate upon receiving the initial SIGTERM signal. This
           can be achieved by configuring LimitCORE= and setting
           FinalKillSignal= to either SIGQUIT or SIGABRT. Defaults to
           SIGKILL.
```

So when you `systemctl stop *.service`,  systemd will send a `SIGTERM` by default to the main process in the service.  If the process doesn't exit within `TimeoutStopSec` (default 90s), then `systemd` will follow up with a `SIGKILL`.

When you are developing your application, you don't need to be too considerate about the init system.  If you don't want to code a response to `SIGTERM`, and want to simply keep `SIGINT`, you can.  You just need to ensure any systemd service files you ship contain `KillSignal=SIGINT`.

I have not read anything to suggest `systemd` skips `KillSignal=` upon a reboot. If you ever see "Waiting for ..." when shutting down, that's `systemd` waiting for things to respond to `KillSignal`.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, all init systems implement more or less the same behavior. Which is, they send SIGTERM and wait for some amount of time and if the process does not terminate gracefully, they send a SIGKILL. I believe systemd works the same way. I could be wrong tho. The best way to know for sure is to test it.

I would recommend reading the description of the various signals and what do they mean and make your application react to them accordingly.

If your application is supposed to run as a long-lasting process, you should consider creating a systemd unit for it. This way, you will be able to control exactly what systemd should do with it when the system is shutting down.