# Why PID 1 send SIGTERM

Tags: linux, systemd, kernel, process, signals

I had this problem for a few days.
A process, in this case qbittorrent, will stop after a few minutes.

Looking at logs it seems that it just caught a SIGTERM.
Alright so I used `strace -p {PID} -e 'trace=!all'` to debug and I've got:

```
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1, si_uid=0} ---
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1, si_uid=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I cannot figure why PID 1 send a SIGTERM to this process. It used to work a few days ago, I didn't change anything on this system.

By the way sytem wide CPU and RAM usage remain low (let's say below 30%).

Any idea how to investigate further ?

Comment: PID 1 is the system init process. Maybe this helps: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/when-does-the-system-send-a-sigterm-to-a-process?rq=1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/when-does-the-system-send-a-sigterm-to-a-process?rq=1)

Comment: There is https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3911291 . But it is behind a pay wall... Basically it says that there might be missing symlinks to shared libs that systemd is using. Use rescue disk to boot the system, chroot, use rpm -Va to find problems.